# Variables set with task.setvariable are not working in if conditions

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have the following issue:

When setting variables with task.setvariable, variables are not available in if condition from another task level.

Example:

```
steps: 
         - script: |
             echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=env]prod"
           
         - task: AzureKeyVault@1
           ${{ if eq(variables[‘env’], ‘prod’) }}:
              azureSubscription: ‘vault01’
              KeyVaultName: ‘vaultxyz’
```

I am getting the following error:

Input required: ConnectedServiceName

If I am running another script task with echo variable is working. But why variables are not available on the azure context?

I tried to use it as variables. but still not working.

Later edit: After a good search it seems the ${{ }} expressions are checked at compile phase not on the runtime so those variables are not existing, also calling a task like azureKeyVault with defined runtime variables is not working.
Any idea how to force azure devops to take in consideration my runtime variables?

Answer (score -1):

Seems my issue is because azureSubscription parameter from AzureKeyVault task can take only literal parameters, no variables accepted.

Comment: No, the problem is that you can't use variables created at runtime in compilation-time expressions.

Comment: This was my first thought too but after I ve set the azureSubscription as normal variable or parameter, I still got this: ‘ There was a resource authorization issue: "The pipeline is not valid. Job PrimaryIaaSDeployment: Step input azureSubscription references service connection $(EnvironmentSubscriptionName) which could not be found. The service connection does not exist or has not been authorized for use. For authorization details, refer to https://aka.ms/yamlauthz.’  So if using parameters which are given at compile time, you will get this error. There is a GitHub issue raised on this.